How do you load tailwind css for different base paths on the same domain?
I am working on a big project which used NextJs as frontend (written using Typescript) and Tailwind as css provider. However, the project is divided into

Guest User App
User App (Authenticated Pages)
Vendor App (Authenticated Pages)
Admin/SuperAdmin App (Authenticated Pages)

They have their own base paths and hosted on separate ec2 containers and ports. All the apps point to one common domain as their entrypoint, example.com. A Application LB is setup to redirect requests based on respective base paths as given below:
Paths:
{Domain:Port}/              - Guest User
{Domain:Port}/portal/user   - User (Authenticated User)
{Domain:Port}/portal/vendor - Vendor (Authenticated Project
{Domain:Port}/portal/admin  - Admin (Authenticated Admin)

The Challenge
The issue being faced is that tailwind css loads up for / or Guest user and for Authenticated User, which is on container 1. However, for vendor and admin, which are deployed on different containers (2 and 3 respectively) and ports, it doesn't load up correctly.
On checking the browser console, the _next/static/css url is showing up for / domain or redirecting on that domain for all instances and not on respective base paths. This is causing the other apps to not have their own css loaded up.
Please assist on this issue as we are stuck without production deployment due to this.
